# Security access in NativeScript Angular app

Tags: angular, security, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm starting to learn `NativeScript Angular` (I'm used to develop webapp/websites using `Angular`) and I'm still kind of confused on how to create some restricted access on the NativeScript app, or to restrict a specific route and/or sets of routes.

For example, in Angular I use `uiRouter` to define some data, like this:

```
data: {
    requireLogin: true
}
```

In each page transition I check if there is a valid token to garantee access to that user. On the `NativeScript` I was thinking about it and could do the same thing, I just don't know, since I'm very new to `NativeScript` and I don't know if this would go against any best practices, or common security scenarios.

For example, I'll be setting the token on the `Application Settings` after the *login*, something like this:

```
submit() {
    // process the login here
    if ( success ) {
        setString(AppSettings.authToken, authToken );
    }
}
```

And then I would set the routes to have a parent route with a parent component where I will check for this token, eg:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        if ( !getString(AppSettings.authToken)) {
            return this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
        }
    }
}
```

This way I would check if the user has a valid session when accessing the app on a restricted area.

However, for example, in a normal `Angular` Application I also make use of interceptor, to check in every `http` request if the `authToken` is still valid.

How am I supposed to do in this case?

I tried to find any material on `NativeScript Angular` security but didn't found any. is there any place where I can read more about this?

What should I have in mind when dealing with this type of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Angular's [route guards](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html#guard-types)

Basic example for canActivate route guard in NativeScript

```
class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private nav: RouterExtensions) {
    }

    canActivate() {
        if (this.loginService.isLogged) {
            console.log("AuthGuard: authenticated");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("AuthGuard: redirecting to login");
            this.nav.navigate(["/login"]);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Based on this [test application](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/ng-sample/app/examples/router/login-test.ts#L138-L154)

[The same deal](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/master/app/auth-guard.service.ts) in a real demo application. [Here](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/cd74e8134d15003f8aac1d1ee09897adfab44237/app/groceries/groceries.routing.ts#L8) is the actual usage of this guard in the Sample-Groceries app.